# Finding and selecting a keyword on a webpage in AppleScript

Tags: html, applescript

I am currently making a buying bot which opens a website, adds an item to the basket, enters checkout information, and then completes the payment.

However I would like to add a feature to the bot that searches for a keyword within a product on a webpage and identify the pixel location of the keyword to click on it, and then add to basket.

I need help with searching and finding a keyword and the pixel location.

So far, I have been able to find the keyword in the HTML code, but I need to figure out how to find the pixel location of the product.

```
tell application "Safari"

    set keyword to "adPraha"
    repeat
        set myWindow to current tab of first window
        activate

        do JavaScript "window.location.reload()" in myWindow

        repeat while (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is not "complete"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat

        set pageContent to do JavaScript ("window.document.documentElement.outerHTML") in myWindow

        if pageContent contains keyword then
            display dialog "found it"
            exit repeat
        end if
        delay 2 -- wait a bit before running again
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Can you not use JavaScript to click on the element instead ?  Although one thing you don't need to use JavaScript for is to get the HTML source of the web page (`pageContent`)—_Safari_ `tab` and `document` objects have a `source` property that loads the source code of the webpage into it: `set pageContent to the source of the front document` or `the source of the current tab in window 1`.  They also have a `text` property that is similar to `source` but without the HTML tags (so, basically just the plain text parts of the webpage).

Comment: I have never used JavaScript before however if it solved my problem I would be willing. At the moment I would like to search the webpage for a certain keyword, find the position of the keyword on the page, and then click at this position. If you could provide me with the code to complete this task that would be incredible!

Comment: It _would_ be **incredible**, in the original meaning of the word, seeing as it wouldn't be too dissimilar from Jesus turning water into wine in the total absence of grapes, a fermenting agent, and everything else wine is made from.  Essentially, I need to know what keyword you're searching for and on what webpage; I need to see the webpage and examine its source code; and then that should give me all the ingredients necessary to potentially create a script.